# JSch algorithm negotiation fails only in unit tests

Tags: java, junit, powermock, jsch

I'm using JSch to do an sftp get operation. When I run tests using the main method things are fine but using unit tests I run into problems. Here's the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
```

Here's the method that's failing:

```
private ChannelSftp sftpInitKeyfile(String host, String username, String keyfile, int port) throws IOException, JSchException {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    byte[] keyBytes = Resources.toByteArray(Resources.getResource(keyfile));
    jsch.addIdentity(username, keyBytes, null, null);

    Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.connect(); // This line is what's failing

    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    sftpChannel.connect();
    return sftpChannel;
}
```

I did some logging and discovered some differences that I can't figure out. Here's the log when I run my main method:

```
Connecting to (redacted) port 22
Connection established
Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.53
CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
aes256-ctr is not available.
aes192-ctr is not available.
aes256-cbc is not available.
aes192-cbc is not available.
CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
```

And here's the log when I run my unit test:

```
Connecting to (redacted) port 22
Connection established
Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.53
CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
aes256-ctr is not available.
aes192-ctr is not available.
aes128-ctr is not available.
aes256-cbc is not available.
aes192-cbc is not available.
aes128-cbc is not available.
3des-ctr is not available.
CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
ecdh-sha2-nistp256 is not available.
ecdh-sha2-nistp384 is not available.
ecdh-sha2-nistp521 is not available.
CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
```

Notice there are more "not available" messages in the 2nd log than the first, most notably aes128-ctr under ciphers and ecdh-sha2-nistp256 under kexes. I don't understand why, they are both calling the same code with the same libraries. This happens whether I run my unit tests in IntelliJ or via mvn test on the command line. What could be causing this? I'm running JUnit 4.1.2 with powermock 1.6.2.

Here's one of the tests that's failing with supporting code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( {DCGSGenerator.class, DocumentHelper.class, ZipFile.class, String.class, IOUtils.class, JBlocksClassificationToVisibility.class} )
public class DCGSGeneratorTest {

    public static Properties properties;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {

        InputStream propertiesStream = DCGSGeneratorTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ezbake-config.properties");
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(propertiesStream);
    }

    @Test
    public void generateTest() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DCGSGenerator.class);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(DCGSGenerator.class, "deleteFile", any(String.class));
        PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(DCGSGenerator.class, "classificationFromDoc", any(Document.class));

        DCGSGenerator generator = PowerMockito.spy(createGenerator("sample_data"));

        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(generator, "outputToPipes", Mockito.isA(Visibility.class), Mockito.isA(String.class));

        generator.generate();

        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(generator, VerificationModeFactory.times(7)).invoke("outputToPipes", Mockito.isA(Visibility.class), Mockito.isA(String.class));
    }

    private DCGSGenerator createGenerator(String dir) {
        return new DCGSGenerator(
                properties.getProperty("dcgs.input.sftp.host"),
                properties.getProperty("dcgs.input.sftp.username"),
                null,//properties.getProperty("dcgs.input.sftp.password", null),
                properties.getProperty("dcgs.input.sftp.keyfile", null),
                22,
                String.format("%s/%s", properties.getProperty("dcgs.input.sftp.path"), dir)
        );
    }
}
```

Here's my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream propertiesStream = DCGSGenerator.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ezbake-config.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(propertiesStream);
    DCGSGenerator gen = new DCGSGenerator(
            properties.getProperty("dcgs.input.sftp.host"),
            properties.getProperty("dcgs.input.sftp.username"),
            null,//properties.getProperty("dcgs.input.sftp.password", null),
            properties.getProperty("dcgs.input.sftp.keyfile", null),
            22,
            properties.getProperty("dcgs.input.sftp.path")
    );
    gen.generate();
}
```

And finally the constructor in question:

```
public DCGSGenerator(String sftpHost, String sftpUser, String sftpPassword, String sftpKeyfile, int sftpPort, String sftpPath) {
        super();

        try {
            this.sftpPath = sftpPath;
            if (sftpKeyfile != null) {
                sftp = sftpInitKeyfile(sftpHost, sftpUser, sftpKeyfile, sftpPort);
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("Must specify either sftp keyfile");
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error initializing sftp connection: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error reading keyfile {}: {}", sftpKeyfile, e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to exclude server-side configuration issues, can you run your test and your regular program with exactly the same parameters? I mean user , password, key, running on the same host, whatever! Obviously there must be a difference

Comment: The parameters are identical except for the last one (path) which is not even used until after the code that's throwing the exception.

Comment: Try capturing the packets with Wireshark

Comment: I figured it out. See below. It was PowerMockito messing something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Even though I'm not explicitly mocking anything related to JSch, it looks like PowerMockito was messing something up.

```
@PowerMockIgnore("com.jcraft.jsch.*")
```

That solves it.